# Erroneous "no diffs found" when importing a patch

Tags: mercurial

I've made changes to 2 files. I've run `hg diff > 1` followed by `revert --all`; then I updated the repo to the new revision. Now I'm trying to import my changes back, but it fails

```
hg import 1 --no-commit
applying 1
abort: 1: no diffs found
```

The diff file `1` is well-formed and not empty. Fun fact: updating back to the revision for which the patch was created still doesn't let me import it.

What's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the encoding of your diff file. If it's not in UTF-8, convert it and try again. There may be byte order marks or something similar messing things up.

Comment: It was exactly that. Turns out, if I run it from PowerShell the diff is saved in UTF-16 and Mercurial doesn't support that. Have to save it from plain cmd.exe on Windows.